# AWS API Gateway : Convert response to XML

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am getting a string value (xml to string) from lambda backend which should be returned to end user in application/xml format. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify an Integration Response that returns XML, along with a mapping template to format XML using the object returned from Lambda.

[image: Sample Integration Response]

I do not believe there is a default format conversion to XML.  A simple mapping template might be like this:

```
#set($root = $input.path('$'))
<stuff>
    <message>$root.message</message>
    <sourceIp>$context.identity.sourceIp</sourceIp>
    <outputs>
        #foreach($key in $root.keySet())
        <output>
            <key>$key</key>
            <value>$root.get($key)</value>
        </output>
        #end
    </outputs>
</stuff>
```

Comment: a long time ago but you seem to be able to map incoming xml. Somehow when I send xml my mapping templates is not being used. Do you know what i have to do besides set the application/xml

Answer (score 1):

With reference to [this document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#input-variable-reference), section "Accessing the $util Variable", solved the challenge in a simple JSON to XML transform. I did try the mapping template given earlier here, but it did not work for me.

In my case, my JSON response payload is of the form:

```
[
  {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3"
  },
  {
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2",
    "key3": "val3",
    "key4": "val4"
  }
]
```

Here is the mapping template that deals with it:

```
#set ($arr = $util.parseJson($input.path('$')))
<responses>
#foreach($c in $arr)
    <response>
#foreach ($k in $c.keySet())
      <$k>$c.get($k)</$k>#end
    </response>
#end
</responses>
```

The key was the parseJson to get a true JSON/Java object. After thi it was smooth sailing.

And the output is of the form:

```
<responses>
    <response>
        <key1>val1</key1>
        ...
    </response>
    ...
</responses>
```

I hope this helps.