# How to transform XML coming from HTTP endpoint to JSON when using the AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

My backend is sending me XML and I want to transform it to JSON using AWS Api Gateway, how should I do it? Can the Mapping Template `$input` field understand XML input?

Comment: maybe do that convert with lambda? then feed the data to api gateway?

Comment: That is an option, you are right. But I was wondering if it was possible to do it without Lambda. I know that the opposite is possible (JSON -> XML), there is a couple of example in AWS documentation. XML -> JSON should be possible to, they are talking about it, but I don't find any info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS API Gateway : Convert response to XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035338/aws-api-gateway-convert-response-to-xml)

Comment: did you end up finding a solution to this?